# Use of Dismount method of the Win32_Volume

Tags: c#, wmi

How can I dismount a logical drive temporarily on my computer in c#? I am looking for a code that gives me similar results

- Dismount/Hide Drives
- //Do some work
- Mount / Show Drives

I had tried this code to renaming the drive letters, but cannot understand how to use the Dismount method

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searchDrives = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume WHERE label = 'Data'");
foreach (ManagementObject Drive in searchDrives.Get())
{
    Drive.Get();
    Drive["DriveLetter"] = "M:";
    Drive.Put();
}
```

This is the Method provided by WMI

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vdswmi/dismount-method-in-class-win32-volume

How should I use it, please?

Comment: Shouldn't you just call [`Drive.InvokeMethod("Dismount");`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject.invokemethod?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)?

Comment: I have used the following code:
bool Force = true;
bool Permanent = false;
Drive.InvokeMethod("Dismount", new object[]{ Force, Permanent});

But it does not disappear the drive from “My Computer”

Comment: And that line of code did execute? What did it return? Did it return 0? Or something else? It returns a uint32  but InvokeMethod only returns object. Cast the return value to an int first.

Comment: @SidraNaz, did you get it to work? I get a 0 (success), but the drive will not be unmounted, nor will it be mounted with the Mount method.